# How to create a tooltip with wrapped text dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a Textblock dynamically and need to display a wrapped tooltip for it.

I have a resource in App.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ToolTipWrap">
   <Style.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
             <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
       </Style.Resources>
     </Style>
  </Style.Resources>
<Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="500" />
</Style>
```

How do I assign the style to the tooltip?

```
TextBlock tb = New TextBlock();
tb.ToolTip = some_long_text;
```

There is no tb.ToolTip.Style property and
tb.Style = (Style) FindResource("ToolTipWrap") gives an error about wrong target type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution..

```
 <Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ToolTipWrap">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"  />
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="100" />
    </Style>
```

Modified max width to 100 for testing(500 width is too long width,For quick testing made it as 100)...

Here is the applying style to tooltip. 
Created new object of 'Tooltip' and assigned 'ToolTipWrap' style to it. Textblock tooltip text is assigned to the 'Tooltip content'

```
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "Test123";
        var tooltipStyle = FindResource("ToolTipWrap");
        ToolTip tooltip = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
        tooltip.Style = tooltipStyle as Style;
        tooltip.Content = "This is an long tool tip example";
        tb.ToolTip = tooltip;
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How about a custom control?

[image]

`TextblockWithTooltip.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Name="root"
             x:Class="WpfApp4.TextblockWithTooltip"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ToolTipWrap">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            </Style>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="100" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TooltippedTextblock"
               Text="{Binding DisplayText, ElementName=root}"
               ToolTipOpening="TooltippedTextblock_OnToolTipOpening">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip x:Name="MainToolTip" Style="{StaticResource ToolTipWrap}" />
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`TextblockWtihTooltip.xaml.cs`

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    public partial class TextblockWithTooltip
    {
        public TextblockWithTooltip()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTextPropery =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(DisplayText),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TextblockWithTooltip),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipTextPropery =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(TooltipText),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TextblockWithTooltip),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string DisplayText
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DisplayTextPropery);
            set => SetValue(DisplayTextPropery, value);
        }

        public string TooltipText
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TooltipTextPropery);
            set => SetValue(TooltipTextPropery, value);
        }

        private void TooltippedTextblock_OnToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
        {
            MainToolTip.Content = TooltipText;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, in my MainView:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainView's code-behind (add control dynamically):

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddTextblock();

            // Not necessary, just want to focus not to the textblock.
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(MainGrid, MainGrid);
        }

        private void AddTextblock()
        {
            TextblockWithTooltip textblock = new TextblockWithTooltip();
            textblock.DisplayText = "Just another textblock with tooltip.";
            textblock.TooltipText = "This is a long long long tooltip.";

            MainGrid.Children.Add(textblock);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I really like this idea for situations with a lot of reusable textblocks and appreciate the effort it took you to write it. For this project a simpler solution above will do.