# Wrap text in ToolTip WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip, word-wrap

I want to wrap the text that shows my ToolTip but it does not work in any occasion.

```
 <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
     <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
     <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ThemeMainForeground, Source={x:Static app:App.Instance}}"/>
 </Style>
```

This is only 1 of the thing I have tried, I also tried

```
TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  MaxWidth="400" TextWrapping='Wrap' />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

and

```
 <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources
```

but nothing was successful.
Please help.

Comment: You copied a Style from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52197765/3137337? Then what is your issue with it?

Comment: It does not work in my case, the first code I have put is my code on which I have tried other things. Try and you will see.

Comment: The Style for ContentPresenter works if properly used. You made something wrong in the code you have not shown.